# Codeigniter: Selecting different columns from 3 tables

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli

Today i encountered a problem developing my app.
I restructured my database.

I have 3 tables for posts, photos, and for the tags of the posts.

I joined the two other tables(photos, tags).

I would like to query the first 3 post with only one SELECT with photos and tags, but only the first row showing up from the results.

Heres is my code:

```
$this->db->select('owner, title, time, LEFT(content, 75) as content, category, url, price, county');

$this->db->from(POSTS_TABLE);

$this->db->join(PHOTOS_TABLE, PHOTOS_TABLE.'.post_id = '.POSTS_TABLE.'.url');

$this->db->join(TAGS_TABLE, TAGS_TABLE.'.post_url = '.POSTS_TABLE.'.url');

$this->db->order_by('time', 'desc');

$this->db->limit(3);

$query = $this->db->get();

$posts = $query->result();
```

My DB structure:

posts table:

```
id, owner, title, content, url
```

tags table: id, post_id (same as the url column from the posts table), photo (the link to the photo)

tags table:

```
 id, post_url (same as the url column from the posts table), tag.
```

Please help.How can i achieve that with only one SELECT and showing up the correct results ?

I cannot use the WHERE clause, since i dont know the exact post_url

Answer (score 0):

Considering column name 'url' is the id of the row

Try:

```
// Code before
$this->db->join('PHOTOS_TABLE', 'PHOTOS_TABLE.post_id = POSTS_TABLE.url');
$this->db->join('TAGS_TABLE', 'TAGS_TABLE.post_url = POSTS_TABLE.url');
// Code After
```

Comment: "Considering column name 'url' is the id of the row"

not really, url is the unique id of the post in the posts table.There can be multiple rows with the same 'url' column in the photos and tags table.